# Brave browser dark mode issue, result came in a white box inside dark mode browser

Tags: browser, box, darkmode, white-framework, brave

[image: [enter image description here]()]

that white part in the image appears sometimes when the search result came.

Browser: **Brave**.

Assumption: this cames after I installing an extension of dark mode. But I uninstall the extension but still the problem is there.